# Two variants of exporting data to Excel via to_csv method, depending on a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a thing.rb model, and two controllers, for e.g.: thingController.rb and subthingController.rb.

Both of these controllers need to offer exporting data to CSV file (there are buttons for generating CSV in views). It works like this: https://www.codementor.io/victor_hazbun/export-records-to-csv-files-ruby-on-rails-vda8323q0 - I'm doing it in a similar way.

I need access to to_csv from my controllers, but if I use the first controller, to_csv method exports one set of attributes and if I use second controller, to_csv method exports a different set of attributes.

Everything would be fine, if I wouldn't need two different to_csv methods. Let's say that first method exports names and emails to Excel. The second one exports phone numbers and nicknames.

I can't do something like: things_to_csv and subthings_to_csv inside my thing.rb model - those are custom methods (to_csv is built-in) and Rails doesn't recognize them anymore.

Can I make something like if or switch statement inside my model and to_csv method, depending on which controller needs this method?

Comment: I don't understand why you cannot use `.things_to_csv`, like `send_data @users.things_to_csv`. Rails shouldn't be affected by that in any way.

Comment: I don't understand either, I guess that Rails needs built-in to_csv method and doesn't allow for custom ones there.

Comment: The problem was somewhere else, things_to_csv worked! I just missed the fact that I specified wrong file format... Sorry guys!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sub model to have a more specific `.to_csv`, e.g.

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.to_csv
    # exports a, b, and c
  end
end

class SubThing < Thing
  def self.to_csv
    # exports d, e, and f
  end
end
```

Now you can SubThing in your `SubthingController` and `.to_csv` exports the desired fields.

Answer (score 1):

define your method to_csv with parameters `def self.to_csv(attributes = nil)`, so you can customize the result?